# Why doesn't GitHub like the % character?

Tags: github, symbols

I have a GitHub repo with multiple C source files. (I won't share a link unless absolutely necessary so that I can't be accused of advertising.) Every instance of the <kbd>%</kbd> character in the C files is highlighted red:

[image: red percent 1]
[image: red percent 2]
[image: red percent 3]

Am I missing something about `%` in C, is this a bug, or is it intentional?

Comment: What does this have to do with git?

Comment: This seems specific to whatever GUI you're using.

Comment: I think you're really asking why the syntax highlighter on Github (presumably it's Github) doesn't like the percent sign...

Comment: The GUI in question looks to me like it's GitHub; I've updated the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub uses [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist/) for detecting languages, and some highlighting issues can be found there (even if it does not directly concern the language detection module)

See [issue 2839](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2839) which does mention

> We use open source TextMate-style language grammars for syntax highlighting, which are available here:
>   https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/grammars.yml
>   Linguist pulls in grammar updates with each new release, which usually happens every couple of weeks.

For C, is is [`textmate/c.tmbundle`](https://github.com/textmate/c.tmbundle/tree/9aa365882274ca52f01722f3dbb169b9539a20ee), which had a percent-related highlighting issue before ([issue 28](https://github.com/textmate/c.tmbundle/issues/28)): you might have to open a new issue there.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this discussion](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/percent-symbol-highlighted-in-c/8305) has a plausible explanation. Here I quote:

> It's highlighting the % because it's assuming that you're making a printf format string, and that you've made it wrong. Unfortunately there's no way to tell it it's not a printf format string short of changing the syntax file.

Comment: That looks like it *specifically* applies to Sublime Text and not necessarily GitHub.